# How to position part of the line after pattern (including it) after 80th character?

Tags: bash

I know that question sounds a little odd but i will try to explain it more.

I have a file `params` that looks like this:

```
3       p       1 1.732051 0 1.9628$/x2r_a/  
4       p       1 1.732051 0 -1.9628$/x2r_a/  
5       p       -1 1.732051 0 1.9628$/x2r_a/  
6       p       -1 1.732051 0 -1.9628$/x2r_a/
```

What i want to achieve is to move everything after (and with) `$` to the right, ie 80th 'place' of a line:

```
3       p       1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                   $/x2r_a/  
4       p       1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                  $/x2r_a/  
5       p       -1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                  $/x2r_a/  
6       p       -1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                 $/x2r_a/
```

We don't know the exact length of the string before the `$` sign. Also the space between must be filled with spaces and nothing more.

As always i need to do it in bash 2.05 probably with sed, awk or sth like that.

UPDATE
I wasn't specific about how file look like so here's more:

```
c ------------------
c Something stupid
c ------------------
c there is a number: 9$/ar_numb/
c a line that looks
1       px      0.9814$/r_a/
2       px      -0.9814$/r_a/
3       p       1 1.732051 0 1.9628$/x2r_a/
4       p       1 1.732051 0 -1.9628$/x2r_a/
5       p       -1 1.732051 0 1.9628$/x2r_a/
6       p       -1 1.732051 0 -1.9628$/x2r_a/
c
c dirty line
7       cz      0.9347$/x05d_a/
c very dirty
41      p       0$/A_Nel/!jl
        1$/B_Nel/!jl
        0$/C_Nel/!jl
        0$/D_Nel/!jl
        $bad element
42      p       1.723051$/A_NEel/!jl
        1$/B_NEel/!jl
        0$/C_NEel/!jl
        0$/D_NEel/!jl
        $kokode nanika kaite kudasai
```

I will not post changed version becouse it would be too long. I want `$[string]` parts to be moved to the right, but those lines without `$` thing will remain as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on kojiro's answer to include the new requirements*

```
awk -F'$' '/\$/{printf("%-79s$%s\n", $1, $2);next}1' ./params
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ awk -F'$' '/\$/{printf("%-79s$%s\n", $1, $2);next}1' ./params
c ------------------
c Something stupid
c ------------------
c there is a number: 9                                                         $/ar_numb/
c a line that looks
1       px      0.9814                                                         $/r_a/
2       px      -0.9814                                                        $/r_a/
3       p       1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                            $/x2r_a/
4       p       1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                           $/x2r_a/
5       p       -1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                           $/x2r_a/
6       p       -1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                          $/x2r_a/
c
c dirty line
7       cz      0.9347                                                         $/x05d_a/
c very dirty
41      p       0                                                              $/A_Nel/!jl
        1                                                                      $/B_Nel/!jl
        0                                                                      $/C_Nel/!jl
        0                                                                      $/D_Nel/!jl
                                                                               $bad element
42      p       1.723051                                                       $/A_NEel/!jl
        1                                                                      $/B_NEel/!jl
        0                                                                      $/C_NEel/!jl
        0                                                                      $/D_NEel/!jl
                                                                               $kokode nanika kaite kudasai
```

Comment: @SiegeX: Please look at the update. I added some lines, becouse there are differences between them.

Comment: @kasper Ok, this answer is sufficiently different that I updated mine to take care of your new requirements

Comment: Not to be overly competitive, but you accepted this answer, which was based on my solution to the *original* problem below, and awarded me no points? Be a good sport.

Comment: @kojiro: The problem with yours is that it adds dollar signs to lines that didn't have them before.

Comment: @Dennis sure, but first of all, that wasn't a problem in the original question (see edits). Secondly, the accepted answer is a modified version of my solution (again, see edits). So I call foul.

Comment: @kojiro I actually edited your answer at first to include '/$/' and told kasper to accept yours because I didn't feel it was right to steal points for such a minor edit.  However, that didn't do the trick because it added `$` to lines where it didn't need it. This is why kasper put a comment to me on your post. I didn't want to continually edit your answer and I felt this working version was sufficiently different to warrant its own answer.  However, you are correct that I should have given credit to you (done). If people want to upvote your answer higher than mine, that's fine by me.

Comment: @kojiro unfortunately, SO innately suffers from the "fastest gun in the west" syndrome. I try to be as fair as I can to minimize this, but I also want the OP to get a working answer in a timely fashion as well and editing others answers is looked down upon (rightfully so).

Comment: @SiegeX which is why askers should take their time accepting answers. There's a rush to answer questions, sure, but must there be a rush to check the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F'$' '{ printf("%-80s$%s\n", $1, $2) }' params`

Comment: As an aside, I also experimented with `column(1)` for a solution. I couldn't get the exact requirements, but `column -ts'$' params` does an elegant job of pretty-printing your input for an arbitrary term width.

Comment: @SiegeX: Well, it works perfect for the lines with `$` but it also adds $ in lines where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# sed '\|\(.*\)\($/.*\)|{h;x;s//\2/;x;s//\1/;:a;s/^.\{1,78\}$/ &/;ta;s/^\( *\)\(.*\)/\2\1/;G;s/\n//}' params
c ------------------
c Something stupid
c ------------------
c there is a number: 9                                                         $/ar_numb/
c a line that looks
1       px      0.9814                                                         $/r_a/
2       px      -0.9814                                                        $/r_a/
3       p       1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                            $/x2r_a/
4       p       1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                           $/x2r_a/
5       p       -1 1.732051 0 1.9628                                           $/x2r_a/
6       p       -1 1.732051 0 -1.9628                                          $/x2r_a/
c
c dirty line
7       cz      0.9347                                                         $/x05d_a/
c very dirty
41      p       0                                                              $/A_Nel/!jl
1                                                                              $/B_Nel/!jl
0                                                                              $/C_Nel/!jl
0                                                                              $/D_Nel/!jl
        $bad element
42      p       1.723051                                                       $/A_NEel/!jl
1                                                                              $/B_NEel/!jl
0                                                                              $/C_NEel/!jl
0                                                                              $/D_NEel/!jl
        $kokode nanika kaite kudasai
# printf "%.1s" {1..90}
123456789111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888889#
```

Explanation:

1. Only edit those lines that contain `$/...`
2. Copy the line into the hold space (HS).
3. Swap to the HS and delete everything but the string `$/....`
4. Swap back to the pattern space (PS) and do the reverse i.e. delete `$/...`
5. Indent the PS with spaces to the 79th column
6. Swap the spaces at the front of the PS with the non-spaces.
7. Append the HS to the PS i.e. add the `$/...` string to the end of the line.
8. Delete the embedded newline caused by the `G` command.

Alternatively:

```
sed '\|\(.*\)\($/.*\)|!{s/.*/printf "%s\n" "&"/;b};s//printf "%-79s%s\n" "\1" "\2"/' params | sh
```

Or with GNU sed:

```
sed '\|\(.*\)\($/.*\)|{s//printf "%-79s%s" "\1" "\2"/e}' params
```